# Differences in binaries produced by gcc for the same code base for different paths

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I've got a code base (C and C++) that when compiled will produce binaries with different checksums, even after `strip` has been run on the binaries.

Doing a diff of the binaries in hex produced the following lines as the only difference:

Binary from Location 1:

```
00000170: 0300 0000 474e 5500 7645 15ec 09f5 2b56  ....GNU.vE....+V
00000180: 0679 e9a4 d49d 29e0 7de8 fb5b 0300 0000  .y....).}..[....
```

Binary from Location 2:

```
00000170: 0300 0000 474e 5500 cf2a 4316 2262 679d  ....GNU..*C."bg.
00000180: 5691 b91a 52a8 29d2 45e8 c204 0300 0000  V...R.).E.......
```

Seems to me like this must be a checksum or something like that. I would suspect a timestamp, except if I clean and then do a rebuild in the same directory, the binaries will have the same checksum.

Does anyone know what this could be? I'd like to make sure my binaries have the same checksum even when build in different locations so they can be verified by my QA organization.

Comment: By locations, do you mean machines, or just file system paths to the source?

Comment: Just different file system paths. So for instance if I pull the source code out of our CM tool into directory A and build I get one checksum, but then if I pull another copy into directory B the checksum will be different, only in this one spot.

Comment: Typically, you will have a build system that produces an "official" binary so you can just distribute and compare to that one. But, I too would like to know why the binaries are different

Comment: @LordOphidian My magic ball tells me the differing section you left out of your question is `.note.gnu.build-id`. The whole point of [build-id](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Developer_Guide/compiling-build-id.html) is to solve the exact problem you mention. If `eu-readelf -n` produces different build-id's for your binaries, then you have a problem.

Comment: @sleeptightpupper That seems to be it. Thanks! Now I just need to find a way to prevent it from being different so when my QA builds it they get the same checksum.

Comment: No way to tell without more information about your build process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As sleep tight pupper said, the differing section is the `build-id`.

You could avoid having the `build-id` section generated by passing `-Wl,--build-id=none` on linking or you could strip it from the ELF with `strip --remove-section=.note.gnu.build-id`.